# How can I use a field from my Persistent model as a path piece in my routes file?

Tags: haskell, routes, yesod, persistent, haskell-persistent

I have a Persistent model like so:

```
Organization sql=organizations
    Id UUID default=uuid_generate_v1mc
    name Text
    UniqueOrganizationName name
    deriving Show Eq Typeable
```

I'd like to use the organization name in my Yesod `routes` file like so:

```
/#OrganizationName/onboarding/business/about OnboardingBusinessAboutR POST
```

Using `OrganizationName` or `UniqueOrganizationName` there gives me this error:

```
/Users/maximiliantagher/Documents/Mercury/hs/mercury-web-backend/src/Foundation.hs:41:1: error:
    • Data constructor ‘OrganizationName’ cannot be used here
        (Perhaps you intended to use TypeInType)
    • In the type ‘OrganizationName’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘OnboardingBusinessAboutR’
      In the data instance declaration for ‘Route’
```

I could use a newtype as a workaround, just wondered if that was necessary.

I imagine the lack of a `PathPiece` instance is a problem, but if it was just that then the error would be `No instance for (PathPiece ...)`.

Using either `OrganizationName` or `UniqueOrganizationName` would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OrganizationName` type is a constructor, because this is what is used in Persistent machinery like `selectList`. In reality, `name` is a parameter of the `Organization` constructor of type `Text`, so you just need `#Text` in your route.